# Calling Web API from SharePoint Page, i.e. NOT a SharePoint Add-In

Tags: sharepoint, asp.net-web-api, office365, jwt

I have successfully followed the instructions from [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-dotnet/) and created and published a Web API project.

I have also tested accessing the root url of my service and am correctly prompted to login first after which I am able to get results back from an endpoint which is protected via an [Authorize] attribute.

The Web API instance is in the same tenancy as my SharePoint Online site. I now want to call the API from a Page in SharePoint with a Code Snippet webpart. I have added some code to call the API and am getting back a 302 redirect to https://login.windows.net/[instance id]/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=... so it appears that is trying to perform a login.

My question: Since SharePoint and Web API are sharing the same Azure AD instance, how do I forward the token of the already logged in user to the API via Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

> Since SharePoint and Web API are sharing the same Azure AD instance, how do I forward the token of the already logged in user to the API via JavaScript?

SharePoint Online and Web API are both secured by Azure AD, but the token cannot be shared across the applications.

In this case, you can consider configuring the single-sign-on (SSO) for your Web App in Azure AD to avoid user inputting the user name and password repeatedly.

[image]

Comment: Yes the web API service is configured as SSO. However, the second part of this requires the client (in this case SharePoint) to be setup with delegated permissions to the service. The Configure option is disabled for the SharePoint Application in Azure AD. How do I work around that?